# Flutter - TextFormField expand not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, uitextfield, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create my own TextFieldForm to use in my app by specific design and I have some troubles in order to expand it if it's the case.

**Currently, it looks like this:**

[image]

**But this is how it actually should look like:**

[image]

So far as I understood, in order to do this, I should set the ***expands*** parameter to **TRUE**
and ***maxLines*** with ***minLines*** to **NULL**.

which should looks something like this:

```
expands: this.expand,
minLines: this.expand ? null : 1,
maxLines: this.expand ? null : 1,
```

The problem is that I'm getting an interesting error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
These invalid constraints were provided to RenderCustomPaint's layout() function by the following
function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1298:17)
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=289.8, h=Infinity)
```

**My CODE for custom text form filed:**

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String helperText;
  final double primaryFontSize;
  final double secondaryFontSize;
  final bool isPassword;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final bool expand;

  String capitalize(String s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);

  const CustomTextField({
    @required this.text,
    this.primaryFontSize = 20,
    this.secondaryFontSize = 16,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.validator,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    this.helperText,
    this.expand = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _helperText = this.helperText ?? this.text;

    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(


        expands: this.expand,
        minLines: this.expand ? null : 1,
        maxLines: this.expand ? null : 1,


        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: validator,
        obscureText: isPassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: secondaryFontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: capitalize(text),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColor.fontColor),
        ),
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: primaryFontSize,
            color: AppColor.fontColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Divider(
                color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor,
                thickness: 2,
              )),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            _helperText,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: secondaryFontSize,
                color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Expanded(
              flex: 9,
              child: Divider(color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor, thickness: 2)),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

**The USED of custom text form field:**

```
CustomTextField(
  expand: true,
  text:
      "British chef, restaurateur, write, television, personality, food city, and former footballer."
      "Born in Johnston, Scotland.",
  primaryFontSize: correctPrimaryFontSize * 0.8,
  secondaryFontSize: correctSecondaryFontSize,
  helperText: "about you",
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
),
```

Can any of you explain to my what I did wrong? Or I didn't understand what ***expands*** it's doing?

Answer (score 1):

just assign

```
maxLines:null,
expands:true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line inside TextField:

maxLines: null,

Answer (score 0):

Set [maxLines](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) property to null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String helperText;
  final double primaryFontSize;
  final double secondaryFontSize;
  final bool isPassword;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;

  String capitalize(String s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);

  const CustomTextField({
    @required this.text,
    this.primaryFontSize = 20,
    this.secondaryFontSize = 16,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.validator,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    this.helperText
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _helperText = this.helperText ?? this.text;

    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: null,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: validator,
        obscureText: isPassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: secondaryFontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: capitalize(text),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: primaryFontSize,
            color: Colors.green,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
                thickness: 2,
              )),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            _helperText,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: secondaryFontSize,
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Expanded(
              flex: 9,
              child: Divider(color: Colors.grey, thickness: 2)),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Use the custom text field like this:

```
 CustomTextField(
    text: "",
    helperText: "about you",
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
 ),
```

Comment: I did that already... you can check my code which I posted above. "maxLines: this.expand ? null : 1,"

Comment: I've just updated my answer. The documentation doesn't say anything about `expands`, you don't need it.

Comment: If I'm doing like this I will get the fallowing error:                                                                         

`Obscured fields cannot be multiline.
'package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart':
Failed assertion: line 206 pos 15: '!obscureText || maxLines == 1'`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question by adding a parameter called "expand" and I'm checking if that parameter is going to be true or not I will do

```
minLines: null,
maxLines: !this.expand ? 1 : null,
maxLength: !this.expand ? null : 200,
```

the full code been:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:FlutterApp_V2/apps_color/apps_color.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String helperText;
  final double primaryFontSize;
  final double secondaryFontSize;
  final bool isPassword;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;

  final bool expand;

  String capitalize(String s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);

  const CustomTextField({
    @required this.text,
    this.primaryFontSize = 20,
    this.secondaryFontSize = 16,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.validator,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    this.helperText,
    this.expand = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _helperText = this.helperText ?? this.text;

    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: !this.expand ? 1 : null,
        maxLength: !this.expand ? null : 200,

        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: validator,
        obscureText: isPassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: secondaryFontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: capitalize(text),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColor.fontColor),
        ),
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: primaryFontSize,
            color: AppColor.fontColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Divider(
                color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor,
                thickness: 2,
              )),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            _helperText,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: secondaryFontSize,
                color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Expanded(
              flex: 9,
              child: Divider(color: AppColor.grayOutFontColor, thickness: 2)),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mentioning expand property try this:

```
 minLines: null,
 maxLines:  null, 
 maxLength: 250,
```